# How Can I Adjust borderWith without space between image and images?

Tags: ios, swift, border

I want to create a borderWith without space on these country flags but still I'm see space between border and flags. Here is my code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var button1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var button2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var button3: UIButton!
    
    
    var countries = [String]()
    var score = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        button1.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button2.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button3.layer.borderWidth = 1

        button1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        button2.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        button3.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor

        countries += ["estonia", "france", "germany", "ireland", "italy", "monaco", "nigeria", "poland", "russia", "spain", "uk", "us"]
        askQuestion()
    }

    func askQuestion()
    {
        button1.setImage(UIImage(named: countries[0]), for: .normal)
        button2.setImage(UIImage(named: countries[1]), for: .normal)
        button3.setImage(UIImage(named: countries[2]), for: .normal)
    }
}
```

And here is my screen;

[image: my screen]

and here is actually what I want;

[image: what I want]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the border to the button. What you need is to add the border to the button's imageView property. Make sure to set its images before adding the borders:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var button1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var button2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var button3: UIButton!
    
    var countries = [String]()
    var score = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        countries += ["estonia", "france", "germany", "ireland", "italy", "monaco", "nigeria", "poland", "russia", "spain", "uk", "us"]
        askQuestion()
        [button1, button2, button3].forEach {
            $0?.imageView?.layer.borderWidth = 1
            $0?.imageView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        }
    }

    func askQuestion() {
        button1.setImage(UIImage(named: countries[0]), for: .normal)
        button2.setImage(UIImage(named: countries[1]), for: .normal)
        button3.setImage(UIImage(named: countries[2]), for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I just followed the tutorial steps from 2019-2020(I guess) so I just wait it works. Is it a new future?

Comment: AFAIK that property has always been available https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624033-imageview

Comment: I got it. Thanks again for your help.